# Angular 13 upgrade, problem with angular-devkit: cannot read property 'styles' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm trying to upgrade Angular from 12 to 13, and after doing `npx @angular/cli@13 update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13` and starting my app, I get the following error:

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'styles')
    at getStylesConfig (/User/my-user/my-app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/webpack/configs/styles.js:79:49)
    at /User/my-user/my-app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/builders/dev-server/index.js:130:43
    at /User/my-user/my-app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/webpack-browser-config.js:72:16
    at generateWebpackConfig (/User/my-user/my-app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/webpack-browser-config.js:61:40)
    at async generateBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (/User/my-user/my-app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/webpack-browser-config.js:123:20)
    at async generateI18nBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (/User/my-user/my-app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/webpack-browser-config.js:70:20)
    at async setup (/User/my-user/my-app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/builders/dev-server/index.js:127:47)
```

This looks like the culprit:

```js
function getStylesConfig(wco) {
    var _a, _b, _c;
    const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
    const postcssImports = require('postcss-import');
    const postcssPresetEnv = require('postcss-preset-env');
    const { root, buildOptions } = wco;
    const extraPlugins = [];
    extraPlugins.push(new plugins_1.AnyComponentStyleBudgetChecker(buildOptions.budgets));
    const cssSourceMap = buildOptions.sourceMap.styles;
```

Here's the relevant part of my `angular.json`:

```json
{
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "main": "src/main.ts",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets"
    ],
    "styles": [
      {
        "input": "src/default-theme.scss",
        "inject": false,
        "bundleName": "assets/themes/default"
      },
      {
        "input": "src/high-contrast-theme.scss",
        "inject": false,
        "bundleName": "assets/themes/high-contrast"
      }
    ],
    "sourceMap": {
      "styles": false,
      "scripts": false
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to put a breakpoint at the following line in `@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/webpack/configs/styles.js`:

```js
const cssSourceMap = buildOptions.sourceMap.styles;`
```

Apparently `sourceMap` is undefined even if it is in my `options`. I tried to change the `outputPath` in my `option` to `test123` to make sure that was the section being read, and I can confirm that it was.

Yet, `sourceMap` is undefined.

Does anybody know what I might be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried removing your `node_modules` and re-installing the packages?

Comment: @JSONDerulo yes, to no avail. I just updated the post with more info.

Comment: Did you find a solution of this issue yet? i am also having similar issue after upgrading to angular@13.1.0

Comment: Yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ngx-build-plus` too needs to be upgrade to the matching Angular version (i.e. 13).

Comment: I get this issue, but when I try to upgrade via `ng update ngx-build-plus --force` I get `Package 'ngx-build-plus' is not a dependency.`

Answer (score 3):

For Angular 13 , upgrade it to 13

```
ng update ngx-build-plus@13 --force
```

Comment: Working after upgrade to angular version 13 from v12

Comment: I get `Package 'ngx-build-plus' is not a dependency.`

Answer (score 1):

After running the following it works perfectly:

```
ng update ngx-build-plus --force
```

Comment: ng update ngx-build-plus@13 --force

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, we could have old version of libraries and packages which didn't update to needed latest version in `package-lock.json`

1. Remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
2. Run `npm i`
3. `ng update ngx-build-plus@13 --force` (for Angular12 to Angular13)